# Java Duplicate Object Creation

Tags: java, object, memory, duplicates, instance

Say I have a simple immutable `Point` class; it contains two `int` fields (`x` and `y`), a constructor, and two getter methods. Now lets say I write the following code somewhere in my application:

```
Point p1 = new Point(1, 2);
Point p2 = new Point(1, 2);
```

My question is, after that code is run, how many `Point` objects are there in memory? Does Java simply create two separate (but identical) instances of `Point` in memory, or is it "smart" enough to create two references to a single object in memory? Finally, if the former is true, and two separate instances are created, is there a way for my point class to insure that all identical instances are actually references to the same object in memory?

Comment: Java uses a String pool to conserve memory, and  you can pool threads if you write to use them, but Java otherwise does not automatically pool references. And even the String pool will fail at pooling if you create a `new String(...)`. The only solution I can see of is to create your own pool and share a reference if it matches one already present.

Comment: `new` always creates a new object. Java doesn't have any support for pooling (other than `String` interning or `Integer` pooling). If you want pooling you'll have to create it yourself.

Comment: `new` means `new`.

Comment: Maybe you want to have a big `Set` full of `Point` objects, and a `PointFactory` class with a method that gets a `Point` from the set if possible, or creates a new one and adds it to the set.

Comment: @SteveKuo, and `Boolean` and `Character` and maybe `Long`, don't forget. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7

Comment: `new` tells the jvm to create a new object in memory, but `Point p2=p1` might not copy the entry p1 to a new memory area as p2. For all these memory explicit management, please forget java, and do these works with C

Comment: You'd have to do the pooling  (often called interning) yourself.  It's not hard: just a map keyed on the arguments, and a "factory" method for creating/retrieving instances.